# Load only part of an image in pygame?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I can load entire images and work with them easily with

```
pygame.image.load("image.png")
```

but if I only want a tiny portion, I have to load the entire image and crop from there.
Is there a way in pygame to efficiently load only a portion of an image?

Answer (score 5):

Load your image

`my_image = pygame.image.load("image.png")`

Create a new surface

`surf = pygame.Surface((X, Y))`

X and Y are horizontal and vertical dimensions in px respectively.

Place the image on the surface

`surf.blit( my_image, (A, B), (C, D, E, F) )`

A and B are the distance from the top left corner. This places the image on the surface A px down and B px left.

C and D are the cropped part of the image from the top left corner. C px down, D px left.

E and F define the image size.

Comment: This does not load part of an image, it loads an entire image and crops it down

Comment: That's precisely what any program would do. You can't just read part of an image. You read the entire image, then trim off the parts you don't want. Images aren't formatted in a way where you can load only pixels from (A, B) to (X, Y). Software has no way of knowing where those pixels are located in the file without the context of all other pixels, due to compression. An uncompressed format like BMP may allow this, but the OP asked about a PNG.

Comment: Most image formats (PNG included) can be read line by line, this mean you can decode and throw away all the lines before the cropped region, read line by line and keep in memory only the relevant part. Then close the file, no need to decode the rest of the lines.

This not saves some decoding and a lot of RAM. (you need only to keep in memory just a line).

Other formats allow random access to certain parts (lines or tiles).

 https://github.com/lilohuang/PyTurboJPEG ha a crop function that does exactly this.

I could not find a python library that supports this operation for PNG.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended use DaFluffyPotato's code

```py
def clip(surface, x, y, x_size, y_size): #Get a part of the image
    handle_surface = surface.copy() #Sprite that will get process later
    clipRect = pygame.Rect(x,y,x_size,y_size) #Part of the image
    handle_surface.set_clip(clipRect) #Clip or you can call cropped
    image = surface.subsurface(handle_surface.get_clip()) #Get subsurface
    return image.copy() #Return
```

His channel
https://www.youtube.com/c/DaFluffyPotato